# Are there smoke alarms that you can connect 12v-24v strobe to for remote notification?

Tags: wiring, switch, smoke-detectors

Are there smoke alarms that you can connect 12v-24v strobe to for remote notification ?

Comment: Think there are if you search under alarms for deaf people, might find what you want, or edit your question with more details.

Comment: Any smoke detector that's part of an alarm system would qualify.

Comment: There are smoke detectors with strobes, e.g., https://www.amazon.com/CORPORATION-710-CS-Hearing-Impaired-Detector/dp/B000ES4EFU/ref=sr_1_6 , and as mentioned above, any smoke detector designed for use in a system, such as used in apartment buildings or in schools, should easily adapt to strobe output.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik  Wow that is expensive, especially when the light is usually just a xenon flash tube, reminds me of those cheap disposable cameras.  Found this one which has both the detector and additional lights available.  https://www.amazon.com/First-Alert-SLED177-Hardwired-Impaired/dp/B07BH5SVGF/ref=asc_df_B07BH5SVGF/?tag=hyprod-20&linkCode=df0&hvadid=241887629712&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=12364061480391368350&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9005131&hvtargid=pla-598376056074&th=1

Comment: Note that residential smoke alarm strobes like the SLED177 are AC mains power *only* -- they don't have a battery to go with their strobe light function

Answer (score 2):

You haven't mentioned a geographic location which would help support a country-specific response. My reply is applicable to USA. I don't have any relation to any of the companies whose products are mentioned, but I've used some of their products personally and professionally.

There are basically two kinds of fire alarms: the basic "all-in-one" found mostly in single-family residential applications, and fire systems found pretty much everywhere else. A full-fledged fire system integrates separate detection like smoke detectors, heat detectors, and pull stations, as well as signaling devices like horns and strobes.

The all-in-one variety pack detection, signaling, battery backup, and interconnect provision all in one device. This is the kind of thing the average person calls a "smoke alarm" or "smoke detector." For example, this unit (photo from firstalert.com):

[image: First Alert smoke detector]

Some brands of the all-in-one type offer accessories that bridge the gap between basic equipment and a fire system. For example, a strobe device and a relay module. If you had one or more detectors to provide the sensing, the relay module could provide the control bridge to your choice of strobes.  (photos from kidde.com)

[image: Kidde relay module]
[image: Kidde strobe light]

Just in case you're looking for a strobe-only or horn-strobe device, here's an example from System Sensor. They're just one of many brands often found in fire systems, and like many of them this particular one can be ordered in red or white, with or without the printed FIRE marking, is dual 12/24 volt capable, has selectable brightness for the strobe and volume for the horn, offered for wall or ceiling, indoor or outdoor, etc.

[image: System sensor P2W]